# Proving non-differentiability in a basic sense

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I've tried to make this question general enough that it solves other users' questions! Perhaps a solution to this post will explain how one might use a basic definition (see $\mathbb{\S}$) to prove non-differentiability.

---

Suppose that $g(x)$ is defined on an interval $a < x < b$ and for any irrational on the interval, $\alpha$, it can be shown that any rational $x = p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfies

$$\Big|\frac{g(x) - g(\alpha)}{x - \alpha}\Big| = \frac{1}{\Big|p - q\alpha\Big|} $$

Also, $g(\alpha)$, for any irrational, $ = 0$.

---

A solution manual somehow uses this fact, in conjunction with the following, to argue that $g$ is not differentiable at any irrational, $\alpha$.

[image]

---

I don't see how non-differentiability follows from the facts above. My understanding is that a proof of non-differentiability would have to imply that:

$$\forall x,c \in (a,b), \forall L \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \epsilon, \forall \delta, \big|x - \alpha\big| < \delta \rightarrow \big|\frac{g(x) - g(\alpha)}{x - \alpha} - L \Big| \geq \epsilon \qquad \mathbb{\S}$$

The facts above only show that if we choose a close enough rational to $\alpha$, the value of $\frac{1}{\Big|p - q\alpha\Big|}$ is larger than some number. But that number could still be less than a given $\epsilon$, I claim.

Comment: oh I see. nvm, solution understood. comment pls if explanation needed